# How to convert a vector to a string without taking up more space ？

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<uchar> bitstream;

stringstream ss;
copy(bitstream.begin(),bitstream.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(ss," "));
    
string bitstream_string ;
 bitstream_string=ss.str();
```

Every element in the vector is a number 0-255, and after turning into a string, it takes up about 4 times more space, and I wonder why

I wonder converting a vector to a sting without taking up more space

---

The reason I wanted to turn the vector into a string was that I tried to compress the vector using an API from ZSTD (a new lossless compression algorithm that Facebook open-sourced), but I found that the contents of the vector were different after compression and decompression.
Because there was a demo that used ZSTD to compress strings, I tried to turn the vector into a string and then compress it, and found that it could be compressed 2.6 times, but the byte used was actually larger, because the string itself is about 200kb (vector is about 50kb).

Comment: how did you measure the space taken by the two?

Comment: How are you measuring space?  With the code above, there's two copies of the string (one inside ss and the other in bitstream_string).

Comment: What is the reason you want to convert the vector into a string? Why are you surprised that a string of numbers (with spaces between the numbers even) take us more space? Why is the string length being larger a problem?

Comment: I think you should ask a new question about the compression/decompression problem itself. But before then please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to create a proper [mre].

Comment: Firstly, you're printing to the stream as `int`, and inserting a space after printing every character.    `uchar`s with values `0` to `9` will be output as two characters (including the space), values `10` to `99` will be printed as three characters, and values `100` to `255` (most of the values) will be printed as four characters.   For example, a `uchar` with numeric value `123` will be printed as `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'` and `' '`.     So ....  I'm wondering why you're surprised that your code is producing a string with (a little under) four times the size of the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

- First you have to account for the space you add between the numbers. That alone will guarantee at least double (almost) the length of the string.
- Secondly, `std::ostream_iterator` uses the text-only operator `<<` to insert into the stream. That means all numbers will use one ***or more*** characters in the output string. For example the number `123` will use *three* characters in the output.

These two together will easily explain that the string length is much longer than the vector lenght.

If you want a string with text, there's no way to work around it being longer than the raw binary data of the vector.